# Android TextView not showing in Nexus 4 4.4.2, changing gravity fixes it

Tags: android, textview, size, gravity, nexus-4

I had a complaint from nexus 4 user. After updating to 4.4.2 his textview disappeared from the screen. What I have found out is that if I remove android:gravity="center" it is back. Also if I make it smaller it is back too.
Why is this happening only on this device and is there a fix?
I would like big text to stay in the centre.
It is inside RelativeLayout and here is xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/cyan"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<Button
    android:id="@+id/sync_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/sync_button"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clear_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sync_button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/clear_button"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/prog_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/prog_button"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clear_button"
    android:text="@string/start_button"
    android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />



<TextView

    android:id="@+id/timer_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="@string/_5_00"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spdTitle"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="left"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/speed"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timer_text"
  android:gravity="right"

    android:singleLine="true"

    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/accuracy_text"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timer_text"
    android:gravity="left"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/accuracy"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ttlTitle"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="left"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/time_to_line"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timetoline_text"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fields_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ttkTitle"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timetoline_text"
    android:gravity="left"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/time_to_kill"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/distance_text"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ttkTitle"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fields_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dstTitle"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/distance_text"
    android:gravity="left"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/dist"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ttk_text"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ttkTitle"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fields_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/speed_text"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_size"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fields_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ttk_text"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I worked around it by:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=19)timerTextView.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.LEFT);
```

This helps but it is not the solution since text is left and it changes on all 4.4. devices. Problem is as I know with Nexus 4 only

Comment: Can you give us the layout code you are using?

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/_5_00"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

Comment: is there a reason you're just not using wrap_content width/height and centerInParent="true"?

Comment: Also, I put this into a relative layout and installed on my nexus 4 with 4.4.2, it worked just fine. There is something else wrong with your layout

Comment: I updated code and put full layout

Answer (score 0):

include the following in you xml it should fix big text to be in center

android:includeFontPadding="false"

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. For example Galaxy Note3 with 4.4.2. works perfect